# SPF and DKIM records for Mandrill on DigitalOcean

Tags: email, dns, vps, spf, dkim

I have a VPS with DigitalOcean and I’m setting up SPF and DKIM records as per the [Mandrill guide](https://mandrill.zendesk.com/hc/en-us/articles/205582267-What-are-SPF-and-DKIM-and-how-do-I-set-them-up-). However, it tells me my DKIM record is not valid.

The error message that I get is:

> This TXT record doesn's look like a valid DKIM record. Try changing v=spf1 include:spf.mandrillapp.com ?all to v=DKIM1.
>   Here's the current TXT record for mandrill._domainkey.cool-house.nl:
>
> > v=spf1 include:spf.mandrillapp.com ?all
>
> You just need to change the TXT record to this:
>
> > v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=MIGfMA0GCSqGSIb3DQEBAQUAA4GNADCBiQKBgQCrLHiExVd55zd/IQ/J/mRwSRMAocV/hMB3jXwaHH36d9NaVynQFYV8NaWi69c1veUtRzGt7yAioXqLj7Z4TeEUoOLgrKsn8YnckGs9i3B3tVFB+Ch/4mPhXWiNfNdynHWBcPcbJ8kjEQ2U8y78dHZj1YeRXXVvWob2OaKynO8/lQIDAQAB;

My records are: [image: screenshot of SPF and DKIM records]

Anyone know what I’m doing wrong?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[This article solved my issue](http://www.tysonmaly.com/mandrill-spf-dkim-digitalocean-dns/).

Tl;dr: add the SPF record without the domain name at the end.

Answer (score 3):

As of this writing your values should be like this:

**DKIM**

Name= mandrill._domainkey
Value= v=DKIM1; k=rsa; p=**YOUR_INFO_**;

Note that in Name you drop your domain after the domainkey. DigitalOcean automatically adds your domain to the end.

**SPF**

Name= @
Value= "v=spf1 include:spf.mandrillapp.com ?all"

Make sure you have the quotes around the value. Mine didn't work without quotes.

in both cases make sure you are creating a TXT record

Comment: putting quotes around the SPF value was what fixed it for me, thanks! - I had the same problem as OP but using mailjet on digital ocean rather than mandrill